# Shifting a byte to the left by 2?

Tags: byte, bit-shift

I need to shift a byte left by 2.  I am looking at an example for something and he had the byte, 0xC0.  And when he shifted it left by 2, he got 0x300.  Now, I am trying to take the byte 0xCF and shift it left by 2.  Is there any way you could explain how to shift a byte left by two?

Or how to put a simple function together in C# or Java to run this?  (Preferably Java).

Comment: So what exactly is the question here? The math behind it? The code (presumably just a `<<` call)?

Comment: You also did not include what language you are using. C, C++, python or what?

Comment: @Mureinik I think so, but how would you go about doing the math?

Comment: @ImranAli I was trying not to program something to do this, since I just need to find how to shift a byte left 2.

Comment: @Madyson shifting left by 2 is essentially just multiplying by 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can shift a byte left by 2, without coding a function.  First, you could use this website: http://www.miniwebtool.com/bitwise-calculator/bit-shift/ and it would do it for you.  Another way is to multiply by 4.  Because shifting left by 2 is the same as multiplying by 4.  So 0xCF shifted left 2 is 0x33C.